# Animating all RotateDrawables inside LayerDrawable

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable

I have two rotate drawables inside a `layer-list` and I'm trying to animate them both as a `drawableleft` on a button. I'm getting the drawables displayed but no animation.

This is my drawable layout in xml (`button_progress_bar_small.xml`) :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <rotate
         android:drawable="@drawable/ic_spinner_small_outer"
         android:pivotX="50%"
         android:pivotY="50%"
         android:fromDegrees="0"
         android:toDegrees="1080" />
</item>
<item>
    <rotate
         android:drawable="@drawable/ic_spinner_small_inner"
         android:pivotX="50%"
         android:pivotY="50%"
         android:fromDegrees="720"
         android:toDegrees="0" />
</item>
```

And this is the code I'm running :

```
    button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.button_progress_bar_small, 0, 0, 0);
    LayerDrawable progressAnimationLeft = (LayerDrawable) button.getCompoundDrawables()[0];
    ((RotateDrawable) progressAnimationLeft.getDrawable(0)).setLevel(500);
    ((RotateDrawable) progressAnimationLeft.getDrawable(1)).setLevel(500);
```

I'm not really sure what is the trigger for the animation to start or whether i should execute something on each `RotateDrawable` (in contrary to a one action on `LayerDrawable`) in order to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, i found a solution for my problem.

i changed the layout to :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_spinner_small_outer"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="1080"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>        
</item>
<item>
    <animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_spinner_small_inner"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromDegrees="720"
        android:toDegrees="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>        
</item>
```

and changed the code to :

```
    button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.button_progress_bar_small, 0, 0, 0);
    LayerDrawable progressAnimationLeft = (LayerDrawable) button.getCompoundDrawables()[0];
    ((Animatable) progressAnimationLeft.getDrawable(0)).start();
    ((Animatable) progressAnimationLeft.getDrawable(1)).start();
```

its not really answering the question but its a good workaround for me with the same animation affect.

Comment: It's crazy noone has anything to say about this issue!

Comment: happened on this, and curious to know if you're able to get independent animation properties for each item; I'm unable to

Comment: If you meant "get each animation rotate independently of the other" than no. i see only one animation. this is a known issue here in SO.

Comment: It's a good answer , help me solve the problem which is how to make seekbar thumb do rotate animation.  Just need set animated-rotate to thumb , then get thumb and transform it to Animatable and start()

Answer (score 0):

You have to animate the level value which ranges from 0 to 10000.

```
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.button_progress_bar_small, 0, 0, 0);  
LayerDrawable progressAnimationLeft = (LayerDrawable) button.getCompoundDrawables()[0];
ObjectAnimator.ofInt((RotateDrawable) progressAnimationLeft.getDrawable(0), "level", 0, 10000).start();
ObjectAnimator.ofInt((RotateDrawable) progressAnimationLeft.getDrawable(1), "level", 0, 10000).start();
```